Not allow to Add New User to Zkteco device??? Push SDK is private?
I using Zkemclient to add new user to my zkteco device with SSR_SetUserInfo() method, it's work, return true. Then I use SSR_GetAllUserInfo(), the user that i just added, it's not contain in this list. Check this user with SSR_GetUserInfo(), return true. I don't know why.
Is push up with SDK acceptable?
Please help. I spent 3 days with it and without results

Have yiu called RefreshData method after SSR_SetUserInfo?

try to use ZkemKeeper.dll StandAlone sdk
you can Register User and Fetch Details Using this sdk
